# Invalid regular expression nothing to repeat exception for email validation using regular expression

Tags: regex

Getting the exception when validating the email using regular expression

Using the below line of code

**.match("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]++@[A-Z0-9.-]++.[A-Z]{2,}+$")**

[image]

Comment: It seems you didnt escape some characters like the double +
Try using an online editor as most descripe issues in the syntax pretty good (https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's the extra "+"s. Have you tried

```
.match("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}$")
```

P.S. you are only matching full-capital addresses without "a-z".